# What causes an xmllint warning?

Tags: xml, lint

I'm currently writing a plugin for our integration server that uses libxml2's `xmllint` command line tool to validate XML files. According to the [manual](http://xmlsoft.org/xmllint.html), xmllint has a `--nowarning` option that suppresses warnings.

Now, my question is rather simple, and I'm probably just missing something blatantly obvious, but what causes such a warning? It's kinda hard to parse the output if I don't know what exactly it looks like :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A warning could be emitted if there is a problem parsing or validating the document.

Here is a simple example in which a warning is emitted because of an invalid xml version:

```
<?xml version="dummy"?>
<note>
  <to>Tove</to>
  <from>Jani</from>
  <heading>Reminder</heading>
  <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
</note>
```

Run it:

```
$ xmllint test.xml
test.xml:1: warning: Unsupported version 'dummy'
<?xml version="dummy"?>
                     ^
<?xml version="dummy"?>
<note>
  <to>Tove</to>
  <from>Jani</from>
  <heading>Reminder</heading>
  <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
</note>
```

The `--nowarning` option only works if you also have the `--htmlout` option set.

```
$ xmllint --nowarning --htmlout test.xml
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
<html><head><title>xmllint output</title></head>
<body bgcolor="#ffffff"><h1 align="center">xmllint output</h1>
<?xml version="dummy"?>
<note>
  <to>Tove</to>
  <from>Jani</from>
  <heading>Reminder</heading>
  <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
</note>
</body></html>
```

Source code for xmllint is [here](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/libxml2/-/blob/HEAD/xmllint.c).

Comment: XML Lint no longer outputs a warning for the given examples but `parse error`s